# ViewModel not passing value from Register Action to Async Register Action in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently customizing the registration page to pass in a companyID during registration. I'm fairly new to MVC best practices so if this isn't the most ideal approach please let me know. I have already modified the IdentityModel to accommodate the CompanyID property.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm modifying the default registration page as a test.

**Observed Behavior**: The correct CompanyID is being grabbed correctly via the lambda expression. It fails to pass the viewModel to the async RegisterController.

Since it fails to pass the viewModel from the other Register action it fails to assign the CompanyID and throws a foreign key error.

```
   // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            CompanyID = _context.Companies.First(c => c.CompanyName == "Company2").Id
        };
        return View("Register", viewModel);
    }


   // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, CompanyId = model.CompanyID };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {



                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any recommendations is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a field for the company id in the view.

In `Register.cshtml`, add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CompanyId" value="@Model.CompanyId" />
```

Or, using the built-in HTML helper:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyId)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked out perfectly, can't believe i forgot to add that into the view.